# Odds of winning a race given the odds of each runner beating each opponent?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say we have three runners: A, B and C, and we have the probability of each runner  beating each individual opponent:

A before B: $0.68$
A before C: $0.42$
B before A: $0.32$
B before C: $0.30$
C before A: $0.58$
C before B: $0.70$

Of course, the probability of A before B is $= 1 - \text{(probability B before A)}$

How would I go around calculating the odds of a given runner winning the race?

I thought I could consider the individual odds independent from each one, so I could just multiply them. Say:

$$\text{Odds of A winning }= \Bbb P(\text{A before B}) \cdot\Bbb P(\text{A before C}) = 0.68 \cdot 0.42 = 0.286$$

But then if I calculate the odds for B and C I get:

$$\text{Odds of B winning }=\Bbb P(\text{B before A})\cdot\Bbb P(\text{B before C}) = 0.32 \cdot 0.30 = 0.096$$

$$\text{Odds of C winning }=\Bbb P(\text{C before A})\cdot\Bbb P(\text{C before B}) = 0.58 \cdot 0.70 = 0.406$$

The three odds should come to 1, but it doesn't add up:

$0.286 + 0.096 + 0.406 = 0.788$ (not $= 1$)

What is it I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the improved formatting, Brian M. Scott.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough information to determine the answer: just knowing the probabilities for each pair is not enough.

Consider the following two possible situations: in situation $X$, all $6$ race outcomes are equally likely. In situation $Y$, runner $A$ cannot come second, but the remaining $4$ outcomes are equally likely. In both situations, the probability that any given runner beats another given runner is $1/2$. But in $X$, the probability that $A$ wins the race is $1/3$, while in $Y$, it is $1/2$.

---

Your numbers are rather messy, but here's an example to show they don't determine what you want (the first column lists possible outcomes of the race, the second lists the probability of the outcome):

Case 1
ABC 0.30
ACB 0.12
CBA 0.32
CAB 0.26

Case 2
BCA 0.30
CBA 0.02
CAB 0.26
ACB 0.42

Both cases satisfy all your conditions, but in case 1, B has probability 0 of winning, while in case 2 this probability is 0.30.

---

As to your own attempt: what you are doing wrong is assuming events are independent when you have no reason to think they are.

Comment: Thanks, Chris Eagle, you're probably right that I don't have enough information, and that I am wrong in assuming they're independent events. I'm not 100% sure I understand your examples, though. In your first example, you say "the probability that any given runner beats another given runner is 1/2", but if A can't finish 2nd, is that still true? As for your second example, you say both cases satisfy my conditions. I guess that means they respect the individual odds I put on the list? But, then, how do you know the odds you are introducing are consistent with those?

Comment: I actually have more information about each runner, although I did think what I mentioned would be enough. Each runner follows a normal distribution with different mus and sigmas. Using those, I calculated the list of probabilities I mentioned in my question. Would that be enough to find an answer?

Comment: So, the way I see it now, my problem is limited to finding the probability than a normal distribution is greater than two others, when all of them are independent (because I consider times for a given runner to be independent from times of the others). Anyone can offer any help with that?

Comment: I have created a new thread for the new question: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/331175/probability-that-a-normal-distribution-is-greater-than-two-others)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and one of the places I originally looked for answers was here. I have to confess I am not a mathematician - my only qualification is O-level maths. Anyway, the best way to look at the problem is one of combinations. You can have AB (where A beats B) or BA (where B beats A), combined with AC or CA combined with BC or CB. So:

```
AB.AC.BC = ABC = 0.68 * 0.42 * 0.3 = 0.0857
AB.AC.CB = ACB = 0.68 * 0.42 * 0.7 = 0.1999
AB.CA.BC = ??? = 0.68 * 0.58 * 0.3 = 0.1183
AB.CA.CB = CAB = 0.68 * 0.58 * 0.7 = 0.2760
BA.AC.CB = BAC = 0.32 * 0.42 * 0.3 = 0.0403
BA.AC.CB = ??? = 0.32 * 0.42 * 0.7 = 0.0940
BA.CA.BC = BCA = 0.32 * 0.58 * 0.3 = 0.0556
BA.CA.CB = CBA = 0.32 * 0.58 * 0.7 = 0.1299
```

So all the probabilities add up to 1 now. Hurray! BUT the 2 combinations labelled ??? are not possible in a race. The 3 outcomes can't be combined in a race situation because every runner loses to another. Adding together the probabilities for these impossible combinations gives 0.1183 + 0.0940 = 0.2123, which is the difference between the OP's 0.788 answer and 1.

However I don't know how to treat these "impossible" combinations. Just ignoring them and dividing the valid calculations by 0.788 doesn't work. Let's use a simpler example:

Say the probability of a beating b = 0.5, the probability of b beating c = 0.25 and the probability of a beating c = 0.25. So:

```
AB.AC.BC = ABC = 0.5 * 0.25 * 0.25 = 0.03125
AB.AC.CB = ACB = 0.5 * 0.25 * 0.75 = 0.09375
AB.CA.BC = ??? = 0.5 * 0.75 * 0.25 = 0.09375
AB.CA.CB = CAB = 0.5 * 0.75 * 0.75 = 0.28125
BA.AC.CB = BAC = 0.5 * 0.25 * 0.75 = 0.03125
BA.AC.CB = ??? = 0.5 * 0.25 * 0.75 = 0.09375
BA.CA.BC = BCA = 0.5 * 0.75 * 0.25 = 0.09375
BA.CA.CB = CBA = 0.5 * 0.75 * 0.75 = 0.28125
```

So the valid possibilities give win probabilities of a:0.125, b:0.125 and c:0.5625. My first thought was to just divide these valid combinations by the total. Eg a=0.125/0.8125=0.1538. But when I use these probabilities and work backwards to check that AB=0.5 and AC=0.25 etc, they just don't add up. c is calculated as 0.6923, but using an excel spreadsheet I know the win probability for each is actually a:0.2, b:0.2, c:0.6. They produce the correct individual match probabilities of 0.5/0.5/0.25 and a monte carlo simulation gives exactly the right figures. I just can't work out a formula that gets me there!

OK I think I got there. Using the simple harville equation we can calculate the probability of the orders ABC,BAC and BCA given the win probabilities of a,b and c:

```
ABC=a(b/(1-a))
BAC=b(a/(1-b))
BCA=b(c/(1-b))
```

So prob(BC)= prob(ABC) + prob(BAC) + prob(BCA)
Similarly:

```
prob(AC)=prob(ABC) + prob(BAC) + prob(ACB)
prob(AB)=prob(ABC) + prob(ACB) + prob(CAB)
```

For prob(AB) I substituted  1-a-b for c then moved the terms around so it was expressed in terms of b then substituted this for all references to b in the equation for prob(BC). Then moved the terms around so it was expressed in terms of a. This is obviously a big equation and it would take too much space to include it here. From there it simplified down to a very simple solution:

```
a=(xy-x)/(xy-1)
```

where a=probability of a winning, x=probability of a beating c, and y = probability of b beating c.For prob(b), x=BC and y=AC. For prob(c), x=CA and y=BA. In the example:

```
prob(a)=((0.25 * 0.25)-0.25)/(0.0625 - 1)
       =0.2
prob(c)=((0.75 * 0.5)-0.75)/(.375 - 1)
       =0.6
```

It would be nice to see a simpler proof because I don't really understand why it works. Now I'm going to look at races with more than 3 runners.

OK it's pretty simple actually. The chance of A beating C is a/(a+c) where a=probability of a winning the whole race and c= probability of c winning the whole race. Doesn't matter how many runners. So in my example 0.75=0.6/0.8. For 3 runners:

```
AB=a/(a+b)
AC=a/(a+c)
BC=b/(b+c)
```

And for 4 runners:

```
AB=a/(a+b)
AC=a/(a+c)
BC=b/(b+c)
AD=a/(a+d)
BD=b/(b+d)
CD=c/(c+d)
```

Looking at the 3 runner example we can rewrite as:
    b=a/AB - a
    c=a/AC - a

we know
    a=1-b-c

so substituting gives:

```
a=1 - ((a/AB)-a) - ((a/AC)-a)
```

and rewriting to get a:

```
a=1/((1/AB) + (1/AC) - (num_runners-2))
a=1/(2+4-1)
a=0.2
```

In the 4 runner example where say AB=0.333, AC=0.25, AD=0.2:

```
a=1/((1/AB) + (1/AC) + (1/AD) - (num_runners-2))
a=1/((1/0.333) + (1/0.25) + (1/0.2) - 2)
a=1/(3+4+5-2)
a=0.1
```

And once a is known,

```
b=a/AB - a
b=0.2
c=a/AC - a
c=0.3
d=a/AD - a
d=0.4
```

So I think the equation is written as:
$
prob(a) = 1/( \sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{x_i} - n + 2)
$
where n= number of runners and $ x_2 $ = probability A beats B, $ x_3 $ = probability A beats C etc