# Probability that a normal distribution is greater than two others

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given 3 independent variables with normal distributions, how can I calculate the probability that one of them will be greater than the other two simultaneously?

So, how to calculate $P ((A>B) \bigcap (A>C))$ with
$A=N(\mu_A,\sigma_A)$
$B=N(\mu_B,\sigma_B)$
$C=N(\mu_C,\sigma_C)$

I know how to calculate $P(A>B)$, since $P(A>B) = P(A-B>0)$, where $A-B$ has a normal distribution with $\mu = \mu_A - \mu_B$ and $\sigma^2= (\sigma_A)^2 + (\sigma_A)^2$

I'm also aware of the formula for conditional probability
$P ((A>B) \bigcap (A>C)) = P (A>B) P(A>C|A>B)$

But I'm lost as to how to calculate $P(A>C|A>B)$ (or any other way to solve this).

Comment: Yes, they are independent, I mention it in my question.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44139/what-is-px-1x-2-x-1x-3-x-1x-n?lq=1

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks! That's exactly it